# Drag items from a collection view and drop in other view IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a collection view with some images. And I have another UIView. I want the image from the collection view to be dragged and drop into UIView such that on dropping on the UIView some action say colour changes. Also the image should remain in its original place after drop.

This is my code for the collection view.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UICollectionViewCell*aCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,5,100,100)];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: [imagePackArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[aCell addSubview:imgView];
 aCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  return aCell;
```

}

I tried panning gesture to implement this however was unsuccessful.

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLog(@"panning");
CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     sender.view.center.y + translation.y);
[sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
```

}

Please see the screen shot. I want to drag the image from the collection view to the cart image (which is in the UIView)
[image]

What approach should I take? Can someone guide me or provide code snippets/links which can help?

Comment: Have you try this Drag and Drop? http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/

Comment: Or try this too. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16572995/2629258

Comment: Yes. But I want to add drag and drag from a collection view.

Comment: Try this, https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: And try this too https://github.com/lukescott/DraggableCollectionView

Comment: Thank you. But all these drag items and rearrange within the collection view. I want to drag it out of collection view and say drop in another view.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. I've found https://bitbucket.org/foensi/ios-drag-and-drop — it's great, but you might need to do something very clever to have the view scrollable AND its items draggable.

Comment: Try enabling paging in collection view

Comment: Hi @user1882758 - Were u able to accomplish this?? Even i have the same problem.Can you plz share a sample code for this?? It would be grateful...Thanks

Comment: Is there an updated swift3/ios10 solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I found a library by [Markus Gasser](https://github.com/frenetisch-applaudierend). You can find it below:

On Github (authoritative): https://github.com/frenetisch-applaudierend/ios-drag-and-drop
or
On Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/foensi/ios-drag-and-drop

It's a very clean library that comes with a sample app. It shows how you can move views from one stack to another; all nicely animated.

**Caveat: Using with UICollectionView**

I've tried it out with CollectionViews: if you register the whole view as a `dragSource` (which the demo shows), I found that you can no longer scroll the content. This is because the drag-and-drop controller's gesture recogniser captures all gesture events and does not pass it through to the underlying `UICollectionView`.

I asked the author about this, and he had this to say:

> I meant to implement a mechanism to provide a different gesture
>   recognizer for dragging, but I never really needed it in my projects.
>   What I'm currently doing in this situation is to define only a subview
>   of the UICollectionViewCell as the drag source. So if the user scrolls
>   over the collection view it'll still work, but dragging from let's say
>   the cell's icon will start drag and drop. Another possible way would
>   be to set a delegate to the UICollectionView panGestureRecognizer and
>   implement
>   -gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer: to fail on other pan recognizers (though I never used this).

So all in all very useful — but I've still got to work out how to make scrolling work.

Comment: Yes! The author implemented a longPressGestureRecognizer soon after I asked about it. This lets the CollectionView scroll. You can use the latest version and see for yourself.